# Unforgiveable/Unforgetable Past Abortion and Miscarriage

Tags: doubt

I knew a few very senior Buddhism Scholars, one of them also start teaching Dharma having an issue as per title above.

The guiltiness is persist more than a decade and the actions below i personally felt inappropriate especially being too superstitious and claim that all those bad luck due to the title above. Kindly Correct me from wrong if any statement here found inappropriate.

1. Body overweight and start having obesity sickness like knee pain. They will claim that the aborted child coming back and bite the knee. I thought it is as simple as due to diet issue (too much sugar and fats) and lack of exercise?
2. Getting a [Spirit tablet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_tablet) for the aborted/miscarriages child and often doing offering like praying, food, toy, etc  - Personally thought the child will remain in the human dimension and refuse to get incarnation yet it will keep playing mind tricks to the person.
3. They will start teaching Dharma and hope the child can listen as well?

Q1) Please someone review the action above is appropriate especially #2 and #3 ?

Q2) Apart the similar [question and answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/22428/miscarriage-and-abortion) and this [post](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/13710/miscarriages-natural-abortions-as-a-result-of-evil-beings), should we focus more in 8 fold path as core resolution and performing often chanting/praying without spirit tablet? Any Sutta/Mantra suitable for this type issue?

I hope can have different angle and views from Theravada, Mahayana, Zen, etc. Well, those scholars i mentioned above are from Mahayana by the way.

Answer (score 2):

From the sutta quote below, you can see that a person's actions while they were alive determines their outcome, and not rituals performed after death.

Also, please watch [this video talk](https://youtu.be/RggiVQ6F0fk) and [this video talk](https://youtu.be/NfJ4yNlt9po) on superstition by Ven. [Ajahn Brahm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajahn_Brahm). In [SN 7](https://suttacentral.net/sn7), you can find many cases where the Buddha criticized superstitions.

In [DN 2](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than.html#livelihood), we find that astrology, palmistry, divination, tea leaf reading, magic, geomancy, dream interpretation, making predictions etc. are considered "animal arts" and wrong livelihood for monks.

From [SN 42.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn42.6/en/sujato):

> Then Asibandhaka’s son the chief went up to the Buddha, bowed, sat
> down to one side, and said to him:
>
> “Sir, there are western brahmins draped with moss who carry pitchers,
> immerse themselves in water, and serve the sacred flame. When someone
> has passed away, they truly lift them up, raise them up, and guide
> them along to heaven. But what about the Blessed One, the perfected
> one, the fully awakened Buddha: is he able to ensure that the whole
> world will be reborn in a good place, a heavenly realm when their body
> breaks up, after death?”
>
> "Well then, chief, I’ll ask you about this in return,
> and you can answer as you like.
>
> What do you think, chief? Take a person who doesn’t kill living
> creatures, steal, or commit sexual misconduct. They don’t use speech
> that’s false, divisive, harsh, or nonsensical. And they’re contented,
> kind-hearted, and have right view. And a large crowd comes together to
> offer up prayers and praise, circumambulating them with joined palms
> and saying: ‘When this person’s body breaks up, after death, may they
> be reborn in a place of loss, a bad place, the underworld, hell!’ What
> do you think, chief? Would that person be reborn in hell because of
> their prayers?”
>
> “No, sir.”
>
> “Chief, suppose a person were to sink a pot of ghee or oil into a deep
> lake and break it open. Its shards and chips would sink down, while
> the ghee or oil in it would rise up. And a large crowd was to come
> together to offer up prayers and praise, circumambulating it with
> joined palms and saying: ‘Sink, good ghee or oil! Descend, good ghee
> or oil! Go down, good ghee or oil!” What do you think, chief? Would
> that ghee or oil sink and descend because of their prayers?”
>
> “No, sir.”
>
> “In the same way, take a person who doesn’t kill living creatures,
> steal, or commit sexual misconduct. They don’t use speech that’s
> false, divisive, harsh, or nonsensical. And they’re contented,
> kind-hearted, and have right view. Even though a large crowd comes
> together to offer up prayers and praise … when their body breaks up,
> after death, they’re reborn in a good place, a heavenly realm.”
>
> When he said this, Asibandhaka’s son the chief said to the Buddha,
> “Excellent, sir! … From this day forth, may the Buddha remember me as
> a lay follower who has gone for refuge for life.”

Answer (score 1):

> should we focus more in 8 fold path as core resolution and performing
> often chanting/praying without spirit tablet

8 fold path is the path of viewing in terms of not-self & dependent origination . Dependent origination is the view that the impersonal element of ignorance is the primary cause of unwholesome actions.

often chanting/praying is not the 8 fold path

obviously the example provided in the question is of a person/mind unable to practise the 8 fold path and abandon identity, personality & self-views

in MN 66, it is clearly taught a new born child has no self-identity, which therefore also applies to an embryo or fetus

yet the individual in the example in the question keeps concocting a personality view of the embryo/fetus and also of the aborter

the individual does not understand the doer of the abortion was the element of ignorance and that the embryo/fetus was mere elements (dhatu)

AN 3.61 says:

> In dependence on the six elements the descent of a embryo occurs

Comment: often chanting/praying is not the 8 fold path   --> Mahayana version somehow i personally i received a message from them to do more but at the same time they need to understand the meaning of the Mantra/Sutta and practice it. Practice is higher priority than pray/chant